# DSolve giving strange error messages solving a PDE

Tags: bugs, differential-equations

**Bug introduced in 6.0 or earlier and fixed in 10.1**

---

Consider this set of PDE $$\left( x^{2}+y^{2}\right) \dfrac {\partial u}{\partial x}+n x y\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}=0$$ have general solution $$u\left( x,y\right) =f\left( \dfrac {1}{n-1}\dfrac {\left( n-1\right) x^{2}-y^{2}}{y^{\dfrac{2}{n}}}\right)$$for $n\in Z$ and $n\geq 2$, where $f$ is an arbitrary function.

However, in *Mathematica*, only solution for $n=2$ can be given. For $n=3$ and $n=4$, *Mathematica* calculates for a long time (I didn't wait for the result).

The key point is when $n\geq 5$, *Mathematica* starts giving strange error messages and refuse to solve the PDE. For example,

```
DSolve[(x^2 + y^2) D[u[x, y], x] + 5 x y D[u[x, y], y] == 0, u[x, y], {x, y}]
(*{{c[x, y] -> C[1][DSolve`DSolvePDEDump`const$19959[1]]}}*)
```

I get

> Function::slot: Slot[DSolve`DSolvePDEDump`iPowerExpand[1]] (in DSolve`DSolvePDEDump`iPowerExpand[DSolve`DSolvePDEDump`iPowerExpand[DSolve`DSolvePDEDump`iPowerExpand[-1024] DSolve`DSolvePDEDump`iPowerExpand[DSolve`DSolvePDEDump`iPowerExpand[<<1>>]^DSolve`DSolvePDEDump`iPowerExpand[<<1>>]]]+<<1>>+<<3>>+DSolve`DSolvePDEDump`iPowerExpand[<<33>>[Slot[<<33>>[<<1>>]]]^<<33>>[5]]]&) should contain a non-negative integer. >>
>
> Root::npoly: (DSolve`DSolvePDEDump`iPowerExpand[DSolve`DSolvePDEDump`iPowerExpand[DSolve`DSolvePDEDump`iPowerExpand[-1024] DSolve`DSolvePDEDump`iPowerExpand[DSolve`DSolvePDEDump`iPowerExpand[<<1>>]^DSolve`DSolvePDEDump`iPowerExpand[<<1>>]]]+<<4>>+DSolve`DSolvePDEDump`iPowerExpand[<<33>>[Slot[<<33>>[<<1>>]]]^<<33>>[5]]]&)[#1] is not a polynomial in #1. >>

I understand that *Mathematica* may not always be able to solve a PDE, but why am I getting those error messages? What do they mean?

Comment: I wonder what form has that `f` in the "general" solution ... Can you share some info about it?

Comment: @belisarius f is an arbitrary function. In other words, no matter what f you choose, $u \left( x,y\right)$ is a solution to the PDE. To simplify the problem, you can ignore the $f$ function and just use what is inside.

Comment: @belisarius Linear and quasilinear first-order PDEs have such a solution.  In `DSolve[D[u[x, y], x] + D[u[x, y], y] == 1, u, {x, y}]` and `DSolve[D[u[x, y], x] + u[x, y] D[u[x, y], y] == 1, u, {x, y}]` the `f` shows up as `C[1]`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Oh, thanks. Ignorance is never limited :)

Comment: @belisarius I just learned that a few months ago myself :) -- never had a course in PDEs.  I think of it like this: An ordinary antiderivative is defined up to a function of no variables (i.e. a constant); an anti-partial-derivative is defined up to a function `n-1` variables, where `n` is the number of variables in the fn./PDE being integrated.

Comment: @FelixZhao It's almost certainly a bug. Internal local variables should never rise to the top.  You should report it to Wolfram Support.

Comment: @MichaelE2 OK, I will write a technical support to them. But in my experiences, when I report a bug, they just say they pass some develop team for review, and no more feedback then.

Comment: That's often my experience, too. I think I've been notified sometimes when it's fixed, but usually not.  I think they usually let me know if the developers disagree that it's a bug.  But things do get fixed over time, so I think reporting it helps.

Comment: OK, it is confirmed as a bug by Wolfram technical support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This bug is fixed in *Mathematica* 10.1.0. (Mac OS X 10.10.3)

```
DSolve[(x^2 + y^2) D[u[x, y], x] + 5 x y D[u[x, y], y] == 0, u[x, y], {x, y}]// AbsoluteTiming
```

> Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information. >>

```
{0.086166,{{u[x, y] -> C[1][Log[-((4 x^2 - y^2)^(5/8)/y^(1/4))]]}, 
{u[x, y] -> C[1][Log[-((I (4 x^2 - y^2)^(5/8))/y^(1/4))]]}, 
{u[x, y] -> C[1][Log[(I (4 x^2 - y^2)^(5/8))/y^(1/4)]]},
{u[x, y] -> C[1][Log[(4 x^2 - y^2)^(5/8)/y^(1/4)]]}, 
{u[x, y] -> C[1][Log[-(((-1)^(1/4) (4 x^2 - y^2)^(5/8))/y^(1/4))]]}, 
{u[x, y] -> C[1][Log[((-1)^(1/4) (4 x^2 - y^2)^(5/8))/y^(1/4)]]}, 
{u[x, y] -> C[1][Log[-(((-1)^(3/4) (4 x^2 - y^2)^(5/8))/y^(1/4))]]}, 
{u[x, y] -> C[1][Log[((-1)^(3/4) (4 x^2 - y^2)^(5/8))/y^(1/4)]]}}}
```

Similarly, it worked with all $n\geq5$, but for $n=4$ and $n=3$, the evaluation is still quite long.