# Error with DSolve

Tags: differential-equations, bugs

I am trying to solve the following partial differential equation for the function $f(x,y,z)$

$\frac{(\alpha -\beta  y)}{1-y^2}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}  + \frac{(\alpha  y-\beta ) }{\sqrt{1-y^2}}\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} \right)-\sqrt{1-y^2} z \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=0$

When solving with *Mathematica* with the following command

```
DSolve[-Sqrt[1 - y^2] z Derivative[0, 1, 0][f][x, y, 
     z] + ((α - 
      y β) (((y α - β) Derivative[0, 0, 1][f][x, y,
         z])/Sqrt[1 - y^2] + Derivative[1, 0, 0][f][x, y, z]))/(
   1 - y^2) == 0, f, {x, y, z}]
```

`DSolve` gives me the following error output, involving this object `` DsolvePDEDump`const$1049 ``:

```
{{f -> Function[{x, y, z}, 
    C[1][(-z^2 + y^2 z^2 - α^2 + 
      2 y α β - β^2)/(2 (-1 + y^2)), 
     x + (1/(2 Sqrt[-(-1 + y^2)^2]))(-1 + y^2) (Log[1 - y] - 
         Log[1 + y] + 
         Log[α^2 + β^2 - 
           2 (1 + y) DSolve`DSolvePDEDump`const$1049[
             1] + β Sqrt[α^2 - 
             2 y α β + β^2 + 
             2 (-1 + y^2) DSolve`DSolvePDEDump`const$1049[
               1]] + α (β - y β + 
              Sqrt[α^2 - 2 y α β + β^2 + 
               2 (-1 + y^2) DSolve`DSolvePDEDump`const$1049[1]])] - 
         Log[α^2 + β^2 + 
           2 (-1 + y) DSolve`DSolvePDEDump`const$1049[
             1] - β Sqrt[α^2 - 
             2 y α β + β^2 + 
             2 (-1 + y^2) DSolve`DSolvePDEDump`const$1049[
               1]] + α (-(1 + y) β + 
              Sqrt[α^2 - 2 y α β + β^2 + 
               2 (-1 + y^2) DSolve`DSolvePDEDump`const$1049[1]])])]]}}
```

A similar problem has been discussed here [DSolve giving strange error messages solving a PDE](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/77176/dsolve-giving-strange-error-messages-solving-a-pde) . An answer claims that the bug has been resolved in Mathematica 10.1.0, but I am getting this error with version 10.2.0.

Comment: Same error occurs for "10.3.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (October 9, 2015)"

Comment: In Mathematica 10.4.0, it returns unevaluated